# Unable to open designer on form in C# 2010

Tags: vb6-migration, visual-c#-express-2010

I have generated a solution in C# 2010 by way of the Artinsoft conversion from VB6.

When I open the new solution in C# I right-click on the forms but there is no "View Designer" option.  I assume this is because something is failing to compile.  What could be the problem and how should I fix it?

Comment: Other than the fact that if it has a valid initialization method, you should be able to see the designer, theres not much to say without seeing the code.  If you can, post the class in question somewhere we can see it.

Answer (score 2):

- Try a clean and rebuild
- Make sure you have proper designer.cs file
- Make sure the initialize method is called from the constructor of your Forms.
- Make sure if there are any custom dlls they are in right places.
- Better create a new app in Windows forms and check how the things are arranged. so that you can compare the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

I would not expect that from a failure to compile, but rather a failure to convert properly.  Even if the class doesn't compile, if it's a form you shouldbe able to see and edit the form portion.

Answer (score 1):

The reason should be marked in the error list if it's failing to compile. It's more likely that it's created it as just a class (that doesn't inherit from Form).

Check that there's a MyForm.Designer.cs (where your form name is MyForm) and also check that the declaration of the class in MyForm.cs inherits from form

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
```

If this isn't the case, it hasn't converted properly, so you may have to inherit from form, drop on the UI controls again and hook them up to any events

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running Visual Studio as Administrator (elevated rights)?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try Shift+F7 key combination?